# Binding value of radio button when i retrieve data

Tags: c#, radio-button, maui, desktop-application

I'm trying to retrieve value of radiobutton which is 'isConforme' in my MAUI c# desktop app.

The value is not properly bind in my view.

Here is my code

**View:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:mct="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FntrAudit.ViewModel"  
             x:DataType="local:NewAuditViewModel"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:FntrAudit.Models"
             x:Class="FntrAudit.Views.NewAudit"
             Title="Nouvel audit" >
   
    <HorizontalStackLayout>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Audit.Themes}"  EmptyView="pas de data">      
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Theme">
                    <VerticalStackLayout Spacing="300000" >
                        <ImageButton                               
                                 x:Name="ThemeButton"
                                 Source="{Binding LogoTheme }"
                                 HeightRequest="50"
                                    Clicked="ThemeButton_Clicked"
                                 ToolTipProperties.Text="{Binding  Intitule}"
                                 CornerRadius="100"
                        ></ImageButton>
                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
           
        </CollectionView>
        <CollectionView x:Name="sousthemes"  ItemsSource="{Binding Audit.SousThemes}" IsVisible="false">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:SousTheme">
                    <VerticalStackLayout>
                        <Button Text="{Binding Intitule}"
                            WidthRequest="350"
                            Clicked="SousTheme_Clicked"
                            BackgroundColor="#AE1439"                              
                            ></Button>
                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>

        <CollectionView x:Name="question" ItemsSource="{Binding Audit.Questions}" IsVisible="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Always" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Question">
                    <VerticalStackLayout WidthRequest="900">
                       
                            <mct:Expander x:Name="questionz" HeightRequest="220" IsExpanded="False">
                                <mct:Expander.Header>
                                    <Grid BackgroundColor="LightGray" HeightRequest="100">
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Intitule}" FontSize="16" Grid.Column="0"></Label>
                                        <Image  Source="exclamation_mark.png"
                                            HeightRequest="20" 
                                            TranslationX="380"
                                            ToolTipProperties.Text="{Binding RappelJuridique}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </mct:Expander.Header>
                                <mct:Expander.Content>
                                    <StackLayout
                                   >
                                        <HorizontalStackLayout    
                                        >
                                            <RadioButton 
                                                     x:Name="conforme"
                                                     Content="Conforme"
                                                     IsChecked="{Binding IsConforme, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                     Value="true"
                                                     CheckedChanged="RadioButton_CheckedChanged"
                                                   >
                                            </RadioButton>
                                            <RadioButton 
                                                     x:Name="nonConforme"
                                                     Content="Non conforme"
                                                     IsChecked="{Binding IsConforme,  Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                     Value="false"
                                                     CheckedChanged="RadioButton_CheckedChanged">
                                            </RadioButton>
                                            <RadioButton 
                                                     x:Name="nonFait"
                                                     Content="non Fait"
                                                     IsChecked="{Binding IsConforme,  Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                     Value="null"
                                                     CheckedChanged="RadioButton_CheckedChanged">
                                            </RadioButton>
                                        </HorizontalStackLayout>
                                        <Entry Placeholder="Commentaire" Text="{Binding Commentaire}" HeightRequest="100" ></Entry>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </mct:Expander.Content>
                            </mct:Expander>
                       
                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
        <VerticalStackLayout>
            <Button x:Name="record_audit"
                    Text="enregistrer Audit"
                    BackgroundColor="#AE1439"
                    Command="{Binding RecordAudit}">
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="generate_PDF"
                    Text="Générer PDF"
                    BackgroundColor="#AE1439"
                    Command="{Binding GeneratePdf}">
            </Button>

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </HorizontalStackLayout>
   
   
</ContentPage>
```

codebehind

```
using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views;
using FntrAudit.DALApi;
using FntrAudit.Models;
using FntrAudit.Services;
using FntrAudit.ViewModel;

namespace FntrAudit.Views;

public partial class NewAudit : ContentPage
{
    private ISocieteUserService _societeUserService;
    private IClientService _clientService;
    private UserContext _userContext;
    public RestService<Theme> _themeService = new RestService<Theme>();
    public RestService<Audit> _themeServices = new RestService<Audit>();
    public List<Theme>Themes { get; set; }
    
    public List<SousThemeGroup> SousThemes { get; set; } = new 
    List<SousThemeGroup>();
    public NewAudit(UserContext ContextCurrent)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _userContext = ContextCurrent;
    
        try
        {
            BindingContext = new NewAuditViewModel(ContextCurrent);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var tu = ex.Message;
        }
    }

    private void ThemeButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        question.IsVisible = false;
        var imgbtn = (ImageButton)sender;
        Theme btnThemeClicked = (Theme)imgbtn.BindingContext;

        if (btnThemeClicked.SousThemes != null)
        {
             sousthemes.IsVisible = true;
             sousthemes.ItemsSource = btnThemeClicked.SousThemes;
        }
        else
        {
            sousthemes.IsVisible = false;
            question.IsVisible = true;
            question.ItemsSource = btnThemeClicked.Questions;
        }
    }

    private void SousTheme_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var btn = (Button)sender;
        SousTheme btnSousThemeClicked = (SousTheme)btn.BindingContext;
      //  btn.BackgroundColor = Colors.LightGray;
        question.IsVisible = true;
        question.ItemsSource = btnSousThemeClicked.Questions;
    }

    private void RadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //if (sender is RadioButton radioButton && radioButton.BindingContext is Question question)
        //{

        //    if (radioButton.IsChecked)
        //    {
        //        // Accédez à la valeur du RadioButton
        //        string value = radioButton.Value.ToString();

        //        // Mettez à jour la propriété IsConforme de l'objet Question
        //        question.IsConforme = bool.Parse(value);
        //    }
        //}

        if (sender is RadioButton radioButton && radioButton.BindingContext is Question question)
        {
        

        if (radioButton.Value.ToString() == "true")
        {
                question.IsConforme = true;
                //    if (e.Value)
                //    {
                //            question.IsConforme = true;
                //    }
            }
        else if (radioButton.Value.ToString() == "false")
        {
                question.IsConforme = false;
                //if (e.Value)
                //{
                //        question.IsConforme = false;
                //    }
            }
        else if (radioButton.Value.ToString() == "null")
        {
                question.IsConforme = null;
                //if (e.Value)
                //{
                //        question.IsConforme = null;
                //    }
            }
    }

    }

    private void record_audit_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var audit = e;


    }
}
```

**viewmodel:**

```
using FntrAudit.DALApi;
using FntrAudit.Models;
using FntrAudit.Services;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using FntrAudit.DocumentGenerators;
using System.Text.Json;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using FntrAudit.Utils;
using FntrAudit.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace FntrAudit.ViewModel
{
    public partial class NewAuditViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private UserContext _currentContext;
        private bool isSousThemeVisible;

        private RestService<Theme> _themeService = new RestService<Theme>();
        private RestService<Audit> _auditService = new RestService<Audit>();
        private RestService<Client> _clientService = new RestService<Client>();
        private Audit audit;
        SqliteDbContext db = new SqliteDbContext();

        private bool? isConforme;
        public bool? IsConforme
        {
            get { return isConforme; }
            set
            {
                if (isConforme != value)
                {
                    isConforme = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsConforme));
                }
            }
        }

        public bool IsSousThemesVisible
       {
            get => isSousThemeVisible;
            set 
            {
                SetProperty(ref isSousThemeVisible, value);
            }
        }
        public Audit Audit 
        {
            get => audit;
            set { audit = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Audit)); } 
        }
        public List<Audit> AuditList { get;  } =new List<Audit>();
        public List<Theme> Themes { get; } = new List<Theme>();

  
        public ICommand RadioButtonCommand { get; }

        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;

            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        public NewAuditViewModel(UserContext ContextCurrent)
        {
           
            _currentContext = ContextCurrent;
            if (_currentContext.IsReprise)
            {
                Audit = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Audit>(_currentContext.CurrentClient.AuditEncours);
            }
            else
            {
                if (Constantes.IsBeta)
                {
                    Audit = db.Audit
                        .Where(a => a.Id == 1)
                        .Include(a => a.Themes)
                        .Include(a => a.SousThemes)
                        .Include(a => a.Questions)
                        .FirstOrDefault();


                   
                }
                else
                {
                    Audit = _auditService.Get(@"https://localhost:7114/api/Audit/" + 1, new Audit());
                }
                    
            }
                      
            RecordAudit = new Command(AuditRecord);
            GeneratePdf = new Command(GeneratePDF);
            GetSoustheme = new Command(GetSousthemes);
          

        }
        private void HandleRadioButton(string value)
        {
            // Logique de gestion de RadioButton ici
            Console.WriteLine($"RadioButton sélectionné : {value}");
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public ICommand RecordAudit { get; set; }
        public ICommand GeneratePdf { get; set; }
        public ICommand GetSoustheme { get; set; } 

        protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        
        public void AuditRecord()
        {
            Client client = new Client();

            if (Constantes.IsBeta)
            {
                client = db.Client.Where(c => c.Id == _currentContext.ClientId).FirstOrDefault();
                
            }
            else
            {
                 client = _clientService.Get(@"https://localhost:7114/api/Client/" + _currentContext.ClientId, new Client());

            }
            var a = Audit;

            client.AuditEncours = JsonSerializer.Serialize(Audit);
            if (Constantes.IsBeta)
            {
                db.Client.Update(client);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                _clientService.Create(client, @"https://localhost:7114/api/Client/updateClient", false);
            }
            _currentContext.CurrentClient.AuditEncours = client.AuditEncours;   
                 
        }

        public void GeneratePDF()
        {
            DocumentGenerator documentGenerator = new DocumentGenerator();
            DocumentContent documentContent = new DocumentContent() 
            {
                Audit = Audit,
                Client = _currentContext.CurrentClient,
                User = _currentContext.CurrentUser
                
            };
            documentGenerator.GenerateDoc(documentContent);
        }
        public void GetSousthemes()
        {
            IsSousThemesVisible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Audit model :**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FntrAudit.Models
{
    public class Audit : BaseEntity, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
       private string code;

        private List<Theme> themes;
        private  List<SousTheme> sousThemes;
        private List<Question> questions;
        private List<QuestionLiee> questionsLiees;

        public string Code
        {
            get { return code; } 
            set {  code = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Code)); }
        }

        public List<QuestionLiee> QuestionsLiees
        {
            get { return questionsLiees; }
            set { questionsLiees = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(QuestionsLiees)); }
        }
        public List<Question> Questions
        {
            get { return questions; }
            set { questions = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Questions)); }
        }
        public List<SousTheme> SousThemes
        {
            get { return sousThemes; }
            set { sousThemes = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SousThemes)); }
        }

        public List<Theme> Themes 
        {
            get { return themes; }
            set { themes = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Themes)); }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        void OnPropertyChanged(string name) =>
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

**question model :**

```
 using System.ComponentModel;
    
    namespace FntrAudit.Models
    {
        public class Question: BaseEntity
        {
            public int ThemeId {  get; set; }
            public int AuditId { get; set; }
            public int? SousThemeId { get; set; }   
            public string RappelJuridique { get; set; }
    
            public string Code { get; set; }
            public string Preconisation { get; set; }
    
            public bool? IsConforme { get; set; }
            public bool HasLinkedQuote { get; set; }
    
            public string? Commentaire { get; set; }
    
    
            //private int themeId;
            //private int auditId;
            //private int? sousThemeId;
            //private string rappelJuridique;
            //private string code;
            //private string preconisation;
            //private bool? isConforme;
            //private bool hasLinkedQuote;
            //private string commentaire;
            //public int ThemeId 
            //{
            //    get { return themeId; }
            //    set { themeId = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ThemeId)); }
            //}
    
            //public int AuditId
            //{
            //    get { return auditId; }
            //    set { auditId = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(AuditId)); }
            //}
    
            //public int? SousThemeId
            //{
            //    get { return sousThemeId; }
            //    set { sousThemeId = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SousThemeId)); }
            //}
    
    
            //public string RappelJuridique
            //{
            //    get { return rappelJuridique; }
            //    set { rappelJuridique = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(RappelJuridique)); }
            //}
    
            //public string Code
            //{
            //    get { return code; }
            //    set { code = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Code)); }
            //}
    
            //public string Preconisation
            //{
            //    get { return preconisation; }
            //    set { preconisation = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Preconisation)); }
            //}
    
            //public bool? IsConforme
            //{
            //    get { return isConforme; }
            //    set { isConforme = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsConforme)); }
            //}
            //public bool HasLinkedQuote
            //{
            //    get { return hasLinkedQuote; }
            //    set { hasLinkedQuote = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(HasLinkedQuote)); }
            //}
    
            //public string? Commentaire
            //{
            //    get { return commentaire; }
            //    set { commentaire = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Commentaire)); }
            //}
    
            //public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    
            //void OnPropertyChanged(string name) =>
            //    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    
        }
    }
```

I have tried many stuff but nothing work when i load the object audit which contains the property isconforme is not bind. when i save audit  i have the good value of isconforme and in my db there no problem. when i spie the property in my code the property is well good.

thanks by advance

Comment: You have three radio buttons all bound to the same bool.  How is that possibly supposed to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Jason comment, you cannot have all three radio buttons bound to the same bool. Also, because you have a `TwoWay` binding to your Question view model you do not need to implement `CheckedChanged`. You will have access to changes from your Question view model.

In the following, I have changed your Question view model so that it has the 3 bool values and each bool value will raise `PropertyChanged?`. Then, in the Audit view model, I hook into the `PropertyChanged?` event and react accordingly. I have supplied a mock `MainPage.xaml` to demonstrate the `Binding` and everything is hooked up without the need to implement `CheckedChanged` nor do I need any special code in my code-behind except what is in the view model.

```cs
// Question.cs ...
public class Question : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _isConforme;
    public bool IsConforme
    {
        get { return _isConforme; }
        set { _isConforme = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsConforme)); }
    }

    private bool _nonConforme;
    public bool NonConforme
    {
        get { return _nonConforme; }
        set { _nonConforme = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(NonConforme)); }
    }

    private bool _nonFait;
    public bool NonFait
    {
        get { return _nonFait; }
        set { _nonFait = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(NonFait)); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged(string name) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
}
```

```cs
// Audit.cs ...
public class Audit : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public IList<Question> Questions { get; } = new List<Question>();

    public Audit()
    {
        Questions.Add(new Question());
        Questions.Add(new Question());

        for (int i = 0; i < Questions.Count; i++)
        {
            var currentQuestion = Questions[i];
            currentQuestion.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => Question_PropertyChanged(currentQuestion);
        }
    }

    private void Question_PropertyChanged(Question currentQuestion)
    {
        int index = Questions.IndexOf(currentQuestion);
        Debug.WriteLine($"Question_PropertyChanged: {index} 
{currentQuestion.IsConforme} {currentQuestion.NonConforme} {currentQuestion.NonFait}");
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged(string name) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
}
```

```cs
// MainPage.xaml.cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public Audit Audit { get; } = new Audit();

    public MainPage()
    {
        BindingContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

```xml
<!-- MainPage.xaml ... -->
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Audit.Questions}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type local:Question}">
            <HorizontalStackLayout>
                <RadioButton Content="Conforme" IsChecked="{Binding IsConforme, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <RadioButton Content="Non conforme" IsChecked="{Binding NonConforme, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <RadioButton Content="non Fait" IsChecked="{Binding NonFait, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </HorizontalStackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @StephenQuan and Jason it's works perfectly. I thought I can have three radiobutton on the same bool even if the bool were nullable.